# Ajax.BeginForm - Get element which makes request

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some ajax forms in my page and I need to get the form Id or some element inside the form when the OnSuccess function is called, example:

```
<li>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
    {
        OnSuccess = "form.onSuccess"
    }))
    {

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TaskId)

        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    }
</li>
```

how can I get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions{OnComplete = "DefaultEditOnComplete(xhr, status, 'Person')"}))
{
    //Person data and submit button
}

function DefaultEditOnComplete(xhr, status, entityName) {

    //xhr - the ajax response
    //status - the response text, ex. "success"
    //entityName - your custom argument, in this example 'Person'

    alert('DefaultEditOnComplete fired for ' + entityName);
}
```

Option 2:

```
 $('form').submit(function () {
   $(this).addClass('activeForm');
 });

 @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions{OnSuccess= "JaxSuccess(xhr, status)"}))
{
    ....
}

function JaxSuccess(xhr, status) {
 var active = $(".activeForm");

 //Do some stuff here
 .....

 //When Done, remove the activeForm class, making everything clean
 $(".activeForm").removeClass('activeForm');
}
```

Option 3:
Abandon Ajax.BeginForm, and substitute for regular form and jquery pairing:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomethingNice", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "CoolForm", @class = "ajaxForm" }))
{
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Rating)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Rating)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Comment)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Comment)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".ajaxForm").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            var jaxUrl = form.attr('action');
            var dat = form.serialize();
            alert(form.attr('id'));
            $.ajax({
                url: jaxUrl,
                data: dat,
                success: function(data) {
                    form.parent().append(data);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status) {

                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: But in my page I have lots of forms, so I need to know to exactly form that was submited. I don't want to set a different name for each one and pass it in parameter.

Comment: @MuriloKunze added another option

Comment: It's a way to solve this. But I think it's not the correct; But I'll mark it as answer if I don't find another way.

Comment: @MuriloKunze yeah, it works, but may not be the best solution.  I apologize, I don't have the experience in AJAXForms that I do in javascript/jQuery.  But, I do my best :)

Comment: Thank, I gave up using ajax helper and just used jquery.

Comment: Thanks!!! Option 1 did the job in my case. :) It's important to match the parameters' names.